# Showing dialog as fullscreen

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to get a fullscreen dialog on smaller devices and normal dialog on larger devices.

From Android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

> Showing an activity as a dialog on large screens
>
> Instead of showing a dialog as a fullscreen UI when on small screens,
>   you can accomplish the same result by showing an Activity as a dialog
>   when on large screens. Which approach you choose depends on your app
>   design, but showing an activity as a dialog is often useful when your
>   app is already designed for small screens and you'd like to improve
>   the experience on tablets by showing a short-lived activity as a
>   dialog.
>
> To show an activity as a dialog only when on large screens, apply the
>   Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge theme to the  manifest element:
>
> For more information about styling your activities with themes, see
>   the Styles and Themes guide.

So instead of a real dialog I have an activity.  That activity looks great on a phone.  Most important part is that the activity has an action bar with a menu button.

When I launch the activity on a larger device the activity does appear as a dialog, however the action bar is removed, along with the menu item that lived in the action bar.

Here is the style I am using:

```
<style name="dialog_theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialog's do not support action bars....bummer.

BUT, dialog's do support toolbars.  I was able to user a toolbar to get a consistent look and feel across the full screen activity and the activity shown as a dialog.